# Why does count(distinct signatory_id) in my query result in an ORA-00600 error?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "EXPCPU_SVS"."TEMP_VW_ZZZ_SVS_DATA_IMPORT" ("ACCOUNT_TYPE", "TOTAL_ACCOUNTS", "TOTAL_SIGNATURES", "TOTAL_SIGNCARDS", "TOTAL_GROUPS", "TOTAL_RULES") AS 
SELECT flag_name            AS ACCOUNT_TYPE,
NVL(TOTAL_ACCOUNTS,0)       AS TOTAL_ACCOUNTS,
NVL(TOTAL_SIGNATURES,0)     AS TOTAL_SIGNATURES,
NVL(TOTAL_SIGNCARDS,0)      AS TOTAL_SIGNCARDS,
NVL(TOTAL_GROUPS,0)         AS TOTAL_GROUPS,
NVL(TOTAL_RULES,0)          AS TOTAL_RULES
FROM
(
SELECT flag_name,TOTAL_ACCOUNTS, TOTAL_SIGNATURES,TOTAL_SIGNCARDS,TOTAL_GROUPS,FLAG_VALUE FROM
(
SELECT flag_name,TOTAL_ACCOUNTS, TOTAL_SIGNATURES,TOTAL_SIGNCARDS,FLAG_VALUE FROM 
(
SELECT flag_name,TOTAL_ACCOUNTS,  TOTAL_SIGNATURES,flag_value
FROM 
(
SELECT flag_name,TOTAL_ACCOUNTS,flag_value 
FROM 
(
SELECT count(*)             AS TOTAL_ACCOUNTS ,
A.HISTORY_FLAG              AS a_history_flag
FROM tbl_sign_account a WHERE a.history_flag IN(0,1,2) GROUP BY a.history_flag
)
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT flag_value,flag_name FROM temp_zz_tbl_flag_mapping
)
ON flag_value=a_history_flag
)
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT COUNT(*)             AS TOTAL_SIGNATURES,
b.history_flag              AS b_history_flag
FROM tbl_signatory b
WHERE b.history_flag IN (0,1,2)
GROUP BY b.history_flag
)
ON b_history_flag=flag_value )
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT count(distinct signatory_id)             AS TOTAL_SIGNCARDS ,
c.history_flag              AS c_history_flag
FROM  tbl_signature_card c
WHERE c.history_flag IN (0,1,2) GROUP BY c.history_flag
)
ON flag_value=c_history_flag
)FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT count(*)             AS TOTAL_GROUPS,
d.history_flag              AS d_history_flag
FROM tbl_sign_group d
WHERE d.history_flag IN (0,1,2) GROUP BY d.history_flag
)
ON flag_value=d_history_flag
) 
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT count(*)             AS TOTAL_RULES,
e.history_flag              AS e_history_flag
FROM tbl_sign_rule e WHERE e.history_flag IN (0,1,2) GROUP BY e.history_flag
)
ON e_history_flag=flag_value;
```

And this is what the error is:

```
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kkqcscpopn_Int: 0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
00600. 00000 -  "internal error code, arguments: [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s], [%s]"
*Cause:    This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program
           exceptions.  This indicates that a process has encountered an
           exceptional condition.
*Action:   Report as a bug - the first argument is the internal error number
```

Comment: "Crashing of Oracle"? Can you elaborate a little with error messages etc.?

Comment: i am just adding the error log ,sorry for that .

Comment: @Ollie i have added the error log

Comment: There's an error returned - your *query* might have "crashed", but certainly not Oracle itself.....

Comment: Did you see the "Report as a bug" part? If you have access to My Oracle Support you can search to see if it's known issue and might find a workaround. (See note 1267257.1  to start with). Of course, you'll need access to raise a service request anyway. You could also try rewriting it - it looks like it could be greatly simplified.

Comment: I have to reopen my connection because it states that the connection is closed when i try to view anything .

Comment: @AlexPoole it works fine if i just write count(signatory_id) but when i include distinct it blows up.

Comment: @AlexPoole but distinct works if i build some subpart of this query again.i cant afford to write whole query again to check and see if it works then (

Comment: if you're asking about Oracle internal error on SO (instead of metalink) you should at least mention exact version. PS: this EAV query can be rewritten using UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ORA-00600 means you're hitting an internal error, essentially a bug. You can look up the details of the error on My Oracle Support; there's a generic document about where to start with ORA-00600 errors, and searching for the argument `kkqcscpopn_Int` will show various known issues - see document ID 1267257.1 for a summary. You will need to know the exact version and patch level to narrow down the possibilities, and to raise a service request if you can't find a match or have any doubt you're seeing the same thing. As the error message says, reporting a bug is the expected action when an internal error occurs.

Sometimes obscure bugs can be avoided by rewriting or redesigning the query you're using. In this case what you have seems overly complicated - not sure why you've put in so many levels of query, or if full outer joins are really needed. If you want to stick to joins to computed counts (rather than, say, having subqueries in the select list) you could try just simplifying it a bit to see if that helps the parser. As a quick first stab, and assuming you will always have records in `temp_zz_tbl_flag_mapping` for the three flag values you're using, I think this is roughly the same:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW temp_vw_zzz_svs_data_import AS
SELECT z.flag_name           AS account_type,
  NVL(a.total_accounts, 0)   AS total_accounts,
  NVL(b.total_signatures, 0) AS total_signatures,
  NVL(c.total_signcards, 0)  AS total_signcards,
  NVL(d.total_groups, 0)     AS TOTAL_GROUPS,
  NVL(e.total_rules, 0)      AS TOTAL_RULES
FROM temp_zz_tbl_flag_mapping z
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT history_flag, COUNT(*) AS total_accounts
  FROM tbl_sign_account
  GROUP BY history_flag
) a ON a.history_flag = z.flag_value
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT history_flag, COUNT(*) AS total_signatures
  FROM tbl_signatory
  GROUP BY history_flag
) b ON b.history_flag = z.flag_value
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT history_flag, COUNT(DISTINCT signatory_id) AS total_signcards
  FROM tbl_signature_card
  GROUP BY history_flag
) c ON c.history_flag = z.flag_value
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT history_flag, COUNT(*) AS total_groups
  FROM tbl_sign_group
  GROUP BY history_flag
) d ON d.history_flag = z.flag_value
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT history_flag, COUNT(*) AS total_rules
  FROM tbl_sign_rule
  GROUP BY history_flag
) e ON e.history_flag = z.flag_value
WHERE z.flag_value in (0,1,2);
```

If you might not have all the flag values in that table/view you might need to go back to full outer joins, but even so removing the nested inline views may make a difference.

Or it may not; I can't produce the error in any of the DB versions I have available, so I can't check if this avoids it. You'll have to do some testing and experimentation. If you get it down to the simplest form you can that makes sense for your data and rules, and you still get an error, you'll have to get Oracle's help.

Comment: Thanks @alex worked great.